# android video recording with duration limit and low quality

Tags: android, video-capture

I need to record video for 8 seconds in my app. I am using **MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE** intent for video recording and using these parameters **(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT)** to set quality and duration limit of video recording. but i encountered a very interesting bug i.e. when i set duration limit to 8 seconds and video quality to 1, its working fine and is recording video for 8 seconds but as soon i changes the video quality to 0 and keeping everything same, the video is now recorded for 21 seconds. I am using **sony Xperia** phone for testing, but when i shift to **HTC**, duration limit not working in any case neither on setting video quality to 1 nor on setting it to 0.

So i don't know what is happening right now. In severe need. please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am using..

```
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    File f = null;

    try {
        f = setUpVideoFile();
        filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        f = null;
        filePath = null;
    }
    objectGlobal.setFilepath(filePath);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 8);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code where you capture your video?

Comment: @Manu i added the code. please check it..!!

Comment: Your code seems fine to me... Looks like a bug

Comment: hmmm.. yeah agreed..!!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this, i too struggling on it.

Comment: ummm.. Actually the problem is when you lower the video quality via MediaStore.Extra_Video_Quality,0 then camera intent no longer works as a video recorder. It starts behaving like creating mms. so I don't thinks there is any solution for that so i decided to create my own video recording module using surface view

Comment: @MukeshRana posting relevant code as answer might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know its bit late to answer this question, but i think i have to, so that if others are facing this problem, they can easily deal with it.

Actually the problem is when you lower the video quality via this

```
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
```

the camera intent no longer works as a video recorder. It actually creates a mms when we try lowering the quality. As far as time is concerned, I don't know whether it is a bug in Android or may be some memory constraints. So the solution I adopted is to make custom video recording class using SurfaceView.
So I am pasting the code of Video Recording from one of my projects.Also the video recorded is almost playable in all android/iOS devices, i have tested so far. Here is my Video Recording Class

```
 package com.mukesh.videorecordingsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class RecordVideoPostsActivity extends Activity implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback, OnClickListener {

    protected static final int RESULT_ERROR = 0x00000001;

    private static final int MAX_VIDEO_DURATION = 8 * 1000;
    private static final int ID_TIME_COUNT = 0x1006;

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private ImageView iv_cancel, iv_ok, iv_record;
    private TextView tv_counter;

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    private List<Size> mSupportVideoSizes;

    private String filePath;

    private boolean mIsRecording = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recordvideo);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        iv_record = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_record);
        iv_cancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_cancel);
        iv_ok = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ok);
        iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_video_start);

        tv_counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        tv_counter.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        iv_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        iv_record.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    }

    private void exit(final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (mIsRecording) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordVideoPostsActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Video Recorder")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                    .setPositiveButton("yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                    stopRecord();
                                    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                                        if (filePath != null)
                                            deleteFile(new File(filePath));
                                    }
                                    setResult(resultCode, data);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("no",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {

                                }
                            }).show();
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (filePath != null)
                deleteFile(new File(filePath));
        }
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }

    private void deleteFile(File delFile) {
        if (delFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        final File file = new File(delFile.getAbsolutePath());
        delFile = null;
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case ID_TIME_COUNT:
                    if (mIsRecording) {
                        if (msg.arg1 > msg.arg2) {
                            // mTvTimeCount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            tv_counter.setText("00:00");
                            stopRecord();
                        } else {
                            tv_counter.setText("00:0" + (msg.arg2 - msg.arg1));
                            Message msg2 = mHandler.obtainMessage(ID_TIME_COUNT,
                                    msg.arg1 + 1, msg.arg2);
                            mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg2, 1000);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        ;

    };

    private void openCamera() {
        try {
            this.mCamera = Camera.open();
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setRotation(90);
            System.out.println(parameters.flatten());
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.lock();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
                try {
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            mSupportVideoSizes = parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes();
            if (mSupportVideoSizes == null || mSupportVideoSizes.isEmpty()) {
                String videoSize = parameters.get("video-size");
                Log.i(EmBazaarConstants.APP_NAME, videoSize);
                mSupportVideoSizes = new ArrayList<Camera.Size>();
                if (!RecordVideoPostsActivity.isEmpty(videoSize)) {
                    String[] size = videoSize.split("x");
                    if (size.length > 1) {
                        try {
                            int width = Integer.parseInt(size[0]);
                            int height = Integer.parseInt(size[1]);
                            mSupportVideoSizes.add(mCamera.new Size(width,
                                    height));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(EmBazaarConstants.APP_NAME, e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (Size size : mSupportVideoSizes) {
                Log.i(EmBazaarConstants.APP_NAME, size.width + "<>" + size.height);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(EmBazaarConstants.APP_NAME, "Open Camera error\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private boolean initVideoRecorder() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.unlock();
        } else {
            mCamera.unlock();
        }
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            CamcorderProfile lowProfile = CamcorderProfile
                    .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
            CamcorderProfile hightProfile = CamcorderProfile
                    .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
            if (lowProfile != null && hightProfile != null) {
                lowProfile.audioCodec = MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC;
                lowProfile.duration = hightProfile.duration;
                lowProfile.videoCodec = MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264;
                lowProfile.videoFrameRate = hightProfile.videoFrameRate;
                lowProfile.videoBitRate = 1500000 > hightProfile.videoBitRate ? hightProfile.videoBitRate
                        : 1500000;
                if (mSupportVideoSizes != null && !mSupportVideoSizes.isEmpty()) {
                    int width = 640;
                    int height = 480;
                    Collections.sort(mSupportVideoSizes, new SizeComparator());
                    int lwd = mSupportVideoSizes.get(0).width;
                    for (Size size : mSupportVideoSizes) {
                        int wd = Math.abs(size.width - 640);
                        if (wd < lwd) {
                            width = size.width;
                            height = size.height;
                            lwd = wd;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    lowProfile.videoFrameWidth = width;
                    lowProfile.videoFrameHeight = height;
                }

                mMediaRecorder.setProfile(lowProfile);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mSupportVideoSizes != null && !mSupportVideoSizes.isEmpty()) {
                Collections.sort(mSupportVideoSizes, new SizeComparator());
                Size size = mSupportVideoSizes.get(0);
                try {
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(size.width, size.height);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File f = null;
        try {
            f = setUpVideoFile();
            filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            filePath = null;
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);

        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
            try {
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d("VideoPreview",
                    "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                            + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("VideoPreview",
                    "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock();
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private void startRecord() {
        try {
            if (initVideoRecorder()) {
                mMediaRecorder.start();
                iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_video_stop);
            } else {
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_video_start);
            }
            tv_counter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_counter.setText("00:0" + (MAX_VIDEO_DURATION / 1000));
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ID_TIME_COUNT, 1,
                    MAX_VIDEO_DURATION / 1000);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            mIsRecording = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showShortToast("problem while capturing video");
            e.printStackTrace();
            exit(RESULT_ERROR, null);
        }
    }

    private void stopRecord() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (new File(filePath) != null
                    && new File(filePath).exists()) {
                new File(filePath).delete();
            }
        }
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        mCamera.lock();
        iv_record.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_video_start);
        mIsRecording = false;

        iv_record.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv_cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv_ok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                                   int cameraId, Camera camera) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo(); // Since API level 9
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        } else {
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            exit(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.iv_ok:
                Intent data = new Intent();
                if (filePath != null) {
                    data.putExtra("videopath", filePath);
                }
                exit(RESULT_OK, data);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_cancel:
                exit(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
                break;
            case R.id.iv_record:
                if (mIsRecording) {
                    stopRecord();
                } else {
                    startRecord();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void showShortToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private File setUpVideoFile() throws IOException {

        File videoFile = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                .getExternalStorageState())) {

            File storageDir = new File(
                    EmBazaarConstants.LOCAL_STORAGE_BASE_PATH_FOR_POSTED_VIDEOS)
                    .getParentFile();

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                        Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
            videoFile = File.createTempFile(EmBazaarConstants.MP4_FILE_PREFIX
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_",
                    EmBazaarConstants.MP4_FILE_SUFIX, storageDir);
        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),
                    "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return videoFile;
    }

    private class SizeComparator implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            return rhs.width - lhs.width;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
        return str == null || "".equals(str.trim());
    }

}
```

and you can simply call this class in your Activity like this

```
if (isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(PostStatusActivity.this,
                                    yourActivity.class),
                            EmBazaarConstants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Your device doesn't support camera",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

and here is isDeviceSupportCamera() function

```
 private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In your onActivityResult, you have to write this code

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == EmBazaarConstants.CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null && data.getStringExtra("videopath") != null) 
                videoFilePath= data.getStringExtra("videopath"); 
}           

}
```

Hope this helps.

** Although we have new Camera2 APIs in android lollipop, but this code still works in android lollipop as well.But still you can change to new Camera2 APIs,if you want.

Comment: Can you paste EmBazaarConstants class here too?

Comment: They are basically constants, you can use yours there like for app name, for request codes, for video name prefix and suffix that can be vid_ and .mp4 respectively

Comment: Can I have R.layout.activity_recordvideo.xml file plz. U can define EmBazaarConstants here in the class its itself so that this class can be used as utility it if working properly @Mukesh Rana